# How can I refresh the pictures in the NimbusPhotos example application?

Tags: ios, nimbus-ios

I'm using the network [Nimbus Photos](http://docs.nimbuskit.info/group___nimbus_photos.html) example application in the [Nimbus Toolkit for iOS](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus).

How can I get the example application to reload all current image data. ( re-request all images / thumbnails, reload the scrubber etc )?

Answer (score 2):

Like with a `UITableView`, you can call `[yourView  reloadData]`.